# Iterate over a dictionary in TestComplete

Tags: dictionary, collections, jscript, testcomplete

I created a dictionary as follows and would like to loop over it and perform some actions.

```
dict.add("a",1);

dict.add("b",2);

dict.add("c",3);

for (var key in dict){

 Log.message("key is "+key+" and value is "+dict[key])

}
```

But the program does not enter the loop.

How can i iterate over the dictionary in Testcomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rounds of hit and trial, i think i have found the solution.

```
var testData = [];
testData["a"] = 1;
testData["b"] = 2;
testData["c"] = 3;

for (var x in testData)
{
    ...
}
```